Align array of structs within 4K boundary
I am trying to reformat some code that uses a struct aligned by a 4096 byte boundary. The struct is basically a 2d array at each point is 2 different uint16 with some padding at each row.
The way the structs are declared are as follows
frame TemporaryFrame0 __attribute__ ((aligned(4096)));
frame TemporaryFrame1 __attribute__ ((aligned(4096)));
frame TemporaryFrame2 __attribute__ ((aligned(4096)));

I am wanting to declare it as
frame TemporaryFrame[3] __attribute__ ((aligned(4096)));

but when I declare as such, it is not stored in memory properly/ the same.
The struct is as such
typedef struct frame frame;
struct frame {
    u8 byte_offset[32];
    row row[FRAME_ROW_SIZE];
};

I have also tried to declare the struct as follows with no benefit.
typedef struct frame frame;
struct frame {
    u8 byte_offset[32];
    row row[FRAME_ROW_SIZE];
}__attribute__ ((aligned(4096)));



"I declare as such, it is not stored in memory properly/ the same" - elaborate 2. What is row


What are these "frames" used for? Why do they need to be aligned on 4K boundaries? What problem does that solve?

Edit the question to provide a [mre], particularly for the assertion that “I have also tried to declare the struct as follows with no benefit.”

What OS / toolchain is this? In some cases, the linker may be limited as to how much alignment it can ensure, and so a request for large alignment might not be honored.

__attribute__ ((aligned(4096))) is a GNU extension, possibly recognized also by certain other compilers.  Since C11, you can use standard _Alignas(4096) instead.  Note well that implementations are not, generally, required to support that particular alignment requirement, but it seems reasonable to assume that any that support it in __attribute__ form will also support it in the standard form.

frame TemporaryFrame[3] __attribute__ ((aligned(4096))); says to make the array TemporaryFrame aligned. Its elements are whatever size they are and are necessarily contiguous in memory. If the size of frame is X, the address of TemporaryFrame[1] is X bytes beyond the address of TemporaryFrame[0], and it is not 4096-byte aligned unless X is a multiple of 4096.
To make the elements aligned, define struct frame to be aligned:
struct frame {
    u8 byte_offset[32];
    row row[FRAME_ROW_SIZE];
} __attribute__ ((aligned(4096)));

If you do not want to change the definition of struct frame, you can use an enclosing structure to provide the alignment, but you will have to add extra code to refer to the structure member:
struct { struct frame f __attribute__ ((aligned(4096))); } TemporaryFrame[3];

…
// Later, where TemporaryFrame[i] would be used, use instead:
TemporaryFrame[i].f


when I declare
nuc_frame TemporaryNucFrame[3];
and the struct as
struct nuc_frame {
u8 byte_offset[32];
nuc_row row[NUC_FRAME_ROW_SIZE];
}attribute ((aligned(4096)));
The struct is still not aligned properly in memory?

@NickBright: I tested it, and it works for me. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Doing
struct { struct frame f attribute ((aligned(4096))); } TemporaryFrame[3];
worked for me. Thank you!
